# Getting Rmarkdown command line arguments printed to the html report

Tags: r, command-line, r-markdown

I'm trying to generate an `Rmarkdown` html report, where `Rmarkdown` is called through the command line. I'd like the header to have information passed through the command line arguments.

Here's my `Rmarkdown` code:

````
```{r setup.n.args, include=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(knitr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(DT))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(Cairo))
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="CairoPNG")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE,out.width='1000px',dpi=200,fig.keep="all")
options(width = 1000)
options(knitr.table.format = "html")

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)
parseArgs <- function(x) strsplit(sub("^--", "", x), "=")
args.df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", parseArgs(args)))
args.list <- as.list(as.character(args.df$V2))
names(args.list) <- args.df$V1
```

---
title: "`r args.list$title`"
author: "`r args.list$author`"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y, %H:%M')`"
output: html_document
  html_document:
      keep_md: true
---


# Table
```{r table,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
datatable(args.df,rownames = FALSE,class='cell-border stripe')
```
````

And here's my command line call to it:

```
R -e "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',output_file='test.html')" --args --title=test --author='test test'
```

Unfortunately no header is created.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `output` part of YAML front matter from

```
output: html_document
  html_document:
      keep_md: true
```

to

```
output: 
  html_document:
      keep_md: true
```

And `--author` is incorrectly parsed.

In command line, changing from

```
--author='test test'
```

to

```
"--author=test test"
```

will fix that.